# How can I pop a listView on top of my map activity?

Tags: android, google-maps, listview, android-studio, overlay

I've got my new application based on Google Maps activity. I set my onMapLongClickListener to add as many new marker as the user want to. But there is my question: I want to set a ListView on the top of my map in order to allow the user to chose between different marker types. How can I set a ListView that appears when I hold a point on the map and then disappear after the selection of one of its items?

Here is my app code, if it can help you on giving me some solutions!

MapsActivity.java

```
package com.example.mancu_000.onclickmarkerlistener;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, OnMapLongClickListener {

    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;

        map.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "OnMarkerListener", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });

        LatLng home = new LatLng(44.42913, 8.84072);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(home).title("Home, bitches!"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(home));

        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(home);
        map.moveCamera(center);

        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17);
        map.animateCamera(zoom);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng location) {
        // Here I'm supposed to implements thee code of the ListView on the top of the map
    }
}
```

activity_maps.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mancu_000.onclickmarkerlistener.MapsActivity" >

    <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks for you support!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

push a dialog to get the list of markers like

```
@Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng location) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builderSingle.setIcon(R.drawable.title_icon_resource);
        builderSingle.setTitle("Select One Name:-");

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>();//create adapter with your markers list

        builderSingle.setNegativeButton();//to exit directly if you want

        builderSingle.setAdapter(arrayAdapter,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener());//set your adapter and listener
        builderSingle.show();
    }
```

hope this will helps you

Comment: I needed to modify a bit your solution, but it give me the correct path to solve my problem, so thanks buddy!! I really appreciate your contribute!!